# Python fails to execute firefox webbrowser from a root executed script with privileges drop

Tags: python, browser, debian, uid

I can't run firefox from a sudoed python script that drops privileges to normal user. If i write

```
$ sudo python
>>> import os
>>> import pwd, grp
>>> uid = pwd.getpwnam('norby')[2]
>>> gid = grp.getgrnam('norby')[2]
>>> os.setegid(gid)
>>> os.seteuid(uid)
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get('firefox').open('www.google.it')
True
>>> # It returns true but doesn't work
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
>>> p = Popen('firefox www.google.it', shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
>>> # Doesn't execute the command
>>> You shouldn't really run Iceweasel through sudo WITHOUT the -H option.
Continuing as if you used the -H option.
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I think that is not a python problem, but firefox/iceweasel/debian configuration problem. Maybe firefox read only UID and not EUID, and doesn't execute process because UID is equal 0. What do you think about?

Comment: Try to start xterm with Popen. May be this is a DISPLAY/xauth issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your environment.  Changing the permissions will still leave environment variables like $HOME pointing at the root user's directory, which will be inaccessible.  It may be worth trying altering these variables by changing `os.environ` before launching the browser.  There may also be other variables worth checking.